# How to create Mysql table in magento extension?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to create new table in custom extension. Table its not created or giving any error.
Here is my 'mysql4-install-0.1.php' file inside local/Pfay/Test/sql/Test_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('Test')};
    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('Test')} (
      `pfay_test_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `full_name` varchar(255) NULL ,
      `email` varchar(255) NULL ,
      `question` text NULL ,
      `product_id` int(11) NULL default '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
        ");
    $installer->endSetup();
```

This is my 'Config.xml' file inside local/Pfay/Test/etc/Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pfay_Test>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Pfay_Test>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <routeurfrontend>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </routeurfrontend>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <test>
                    <file>test.xml</file>
                </test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <test>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                    <frontName>admintest</frontName>
                </args>
            </test>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <test>
                    <file>test.xml</file>
                </test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <menu>
            <test translate="title" module="adminhtml">
                <title>Question Answer</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <set_time>
                        <title>Question</title>
                        <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
                    </set_time>
                </children>
            </test>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <test>
                <class>Pfay_Test_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </test>
            <test_mysql4>
                <class>Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <test>
                        <table>qs_question</table>
                    </test>
                </entities>
            </test_mysql4>
        </models> 
        <resources>
            <Test_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </Test_setup>
            <Test_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </Test_write>
            <Test_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </Test_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <test>
                <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
            </test>
        </blocks>         
    </global>
</config>
```

I spend 5 hours trying to find the solution but could not succeed. It is inserting 'test_setup' in 'core_resource' Table in databse, but not creating table. Please suggest a way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is mistake in file name 'mysql4-install-0.1.php'.It should be 'mysql4-install-0.1.0.php'.

Comment: aton I changed to 'mysql4-install-0.1.0.php' but did'nt worked.

Comment: try checking whether the execution reach inside sql file.Put die('here'); after $installer->startSetup();.and refresh the page.Also I am not sure about this but your folder "Test_setup" should be "test_setup".Check this first

Comment: Also in your config.xml file what is  <routeurfrontend> ?? Is this required?

Comment: it did'nt work. <routeurfrontend> is used for front end display.

Comment: If  die();statement didn't execute than there may be problem in your module. Check whether your module is configured properly.

Comment: aton it is config properly because when i create table manually and add data to it. It display data on frontend and backend.

Answer (score 0):

Module is already installed. thats why installation script is not getting execute. it only executes first time on magento. event you UN-install it. so here you might need update script.

You may change the version of module 
Modify your config.xml to 1.0.0.0

```
 <global>
<resources>
    <mymodule_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Sulman_Custompermissions</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </mymodule_setup>
</resources>
```

and change the install script file name to mysql4-install-1.0.0.0.php and delete the entry from core_resource table and clear the cache and check...

Comment: I changed it to 1.1.0 and delete the test_setup from core_resource. But it did'nt worked.

Comment: Ok, then copy that installation file and rename it to mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0.0-1.1.0.php and in config version should be 1.1.0